# How to fix AMD Vision Engine Control Center seeing my display as CRT?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display, amd-radeon, amd-vision

I'm running an HP Pavilion dv6-3010us, with a Radeon HD 4200 series GPU. I have updated the ATI Catalyst Control Center, and now it's completely changed to AMD Vision Engine Control Center.

I have removed the laptop's monitor and hooked it up to a Dell 2009wt monitor that I bought recently via the VGA connection. I have also manually installed Dell's driver for it, and the Device Manager recognizes it as the 2009wt that it is. However, the Vision Engine Control Center only recognizes it as "Unknown Display," and a CRT at that.

Does anyone know why it's doing this, or some way I can force a manual detection, similar to forcing the monitor driver to update even though Windows thought "Generic Non-PnP Monitor" was best?

Alternatively, will I have more luck using an adapter to hook up the HDMI out of the laptop to the DVI in on the monitor?

EDIT: My HDMI to DVI adapter cable just arrived, and it works perfectly. The settings adjusted instantly when I plugged it in (the monitor was on auto-detect), and now I'm running max resolution with a 16:10 picture!

Should I answer my own question and mark that as best, or just leave the question alone now?

Comment: "will I have more luck using an adapter to hook up the HDMI out of the laptop to the DVI in on the monitor" Probably, why not try it?

Comment: I will try that, as soon as I get one... ---- I just can't believe there's no way to manually tell the software that you have a particular monitor. This is a pretty big design flaw if it's true, especially considering that some LCDs are VGA-only.

Comment: It actually seems to me that the monitor is not properly identifying itself, but hard to say.

Comment: May sound lame, but it's easy to test (if you have one) --- Have you tried a different VGA cable?

Comment: Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit? What's the graphic card hardware ID displayed in the Device Manager? Which driver version are you currently using? Download and run [Monitor Asset Manager](http://www.entechtaiwan.com/util/moninfo.shtm). Select the "Real-time" item from the display IDs list and copy the asset information, then upload the text to http://pastebin.com/. Repeat the same steps for the "Registry" and "Registry-Active" items.